# How to force inclusion of an object file in a static library when linking into executable?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, static-libraries

I have a C++ project that due to its directory structure is set up as a static library `A`, which is linked into shared library `B`, which is linked into executable `C`.  (This is a cross-platform project using CMake, so on Windows we get `A.lib`, `B.dll`, and `C.exe`, and on Linux we get `libA.a`, `libB.so`, and `C`.)  Library `A` has an init function (`A_init`, defined in `A/initA.cpp`), that is called from library `B`'s init function (`B_init`, defined in `B/initB.cpp`), which is called from `C`'s main.  Thus, when linking `B`, `A_init` (and all symbols defined in `initA.cpp`) is linked into `B` (which is our desired behavior).

The problem comes in that the `A` library also defines a function (`Af`, defined in `A/Afort.f`) that is intended to by dynamically loaded (i.e. `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress` on Windows and `dlopen`/`dlsym` on Linux).  Since there are no references to `Af` from library `B`, symbols from `A/Afort.o` are not included into `B`.  On Windows, we can artifically create a reference by using the pragma:

```
#pragma comment (linker, "/export:_Af")
```

Since this is a pragma, it only works on Windows (using Visual Studio 2008).  To get it working on Linux, we've tried adding the following to `A/initA.cpp`:

```
extern void Af(void);
static void (*Af_fp)(void) = &Af;
```

This does not cause the symbol `Af` to be included in the final link of `B`.  How can we force the symbol `Af` to be linked into `B`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out my original attempt was mostly there.  The following works:

```
extern "C" void Af(void);
void (*Af_fp)(void) = &Af;
```

For those that want a self-contained preprocessor macro to encapsulate this:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
# if defined(_WIN64)
#  define FORCE_UNDEFINED_SYMBOL(x) __pragma(comment (linker, "/export:" #x))
# else
#  define FORCE_UNDEFINED_SYMBOL(x) __pragma(comment (linker, "/export:_" #x))
# endif
#else
# define FORCE_UNDEFINED_SYMBOL(x) extern "C" void x(void); void (*__ ## x ## _fp)(void)=&x;
#endif
```

Which is used thusly:

```
FORCE_UNDEFINED_SYMBOL(Af)
```

Answer (score 8):

[MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx) `#pragma comment(linker, "/include:__mySymbol")`

[gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) `-u symbol`

Answer (score 5):

There is a better way to write that FORCE_UNDEFINED_SYMBOL macro. Just cast that function pointer to a void*. Then it works with any function - or data for that matter. Also, why bother with MSVC pragmas when the gcc part of your macro will work for MSVC as well. So my simplified version would be:

```
#define FORCE_UNDEFINED_SYMBOL(x) void* __ ## x ## _fp =(void*)&x;
```

Which is used thusly:

```
FORCE_UNDEFINED_SYMBOL(Af)
```

But it must be used in the program that includes the library that is having its symbols stripped.

Comment: With C++11, you probably can use `auto` and no cast!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `--undefined` option when you build B:

```
g++ -Wl,--undefined,Af -o libB.so ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting those lines into `B/initB.cpp` so that they're (hopefully) forced into the `libB.so` library at link time.

But why do you have to do it in this way at all? Can't you set it up so that the executable references that function (or a caller of it), causing the linker to do the right thing automatically?

Comment: C is actually a scripting language frontend, B is the language engine, and A is a set of native code methods for the engine to use.  We're implementing a pre-existing language that has a well-defined foreign function interface.  A and B are produced by separate teams; we'd prefer to keep everything that the A-team writes in the A directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use **C++0x** features of gcc (*-std=c++0x*), then the *function default template arguments* may do the trick. As of the current c++ standard, default arguments are not allowed for function templates. With these enabled in c++0x, you can do something like :-

In some header file of static library ...

```
template< class T = int >
void Af()
{
}
```

Then in its corresponding cpp file use explicit template instantiation...

```
template void Af();
```

This will generate the symbols for the function `Af` though it is not yet called/referenced.
This won't affect the callers due to the fact that because of the default template argument, you need not specify a type. Just add the `template <class T = int >` before the function declaration and explicitly instantiate it in its implementation file.

HTH,

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work because Af is actually a Fortran procedure.

Comment: Well then, make a 'C' wrapper that calls Af_(...) [u can call fortran functions from 'C' i.e. function name appended by underscore; google nitty gritty details for arguments, i donno abt C++ calling fortran]. Call this 'C' wrapper from C++. BTW, thats how one of the leading financial company that i worked for, managed its antique/crappy code :-)

Comment: It's a very un-obvious code that will likely be removed by a rookie maintainer, 2 years after. At least the macro is clear enough to understand.

Comment: @xryl669, that's why you're expected to include a comment just before/after such definition (and hope the rookie can read comments too.)