# Forcing specific visible symbol export from linked static library with GCC (while excluding other symbols)

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, visibility

I am trying to provide access to a function linked in to an executable from a static library. The original static library defines the symbol with no access specifiers, and I was able to access the function using the method defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991927/how-to-force-inclusion-of-an-object-file-in-a-static-library-when-linking-into-e), which works fine using MSVC as linked in symbols are hidden by default.

However, when using GCC, I need to export the function while using -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL which keeps all other unnecessary symbols from being visibly exported from linked-in static libraries. The symbol in question is not referenced from the main application itself, however third party modules may attempt to dynamically use the symbol externally (ffi etc), hence the use of FORCE_UNDEFINED_SYMBOL.

The only symbols I need exported are those marked visibility default from the main application, and certain imported functions from static libraries (which I may not be able to modify). I know wrapper functions could be used, however I'm wondering if there is any other way.

So, is it possible to export a symbol (visibly) from a linked-in static library, while using -WL,--exclude-libs,ALL, without the use of any additional (version-lists etc) files, or commands/flags? (And without modifying the static library)

Using the following macros (partially) work, however the original function symbol is still .hidden (with __MyFunction_fp exported as visible).

```
#define APIEXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#define FORCE_UNDEFINED_SYMBOL(x) extern APIEXPORT void x(void); APIEXPORT void* __ ## x ## _fp =(void*)&x;
FORCE_UNDEFINED_SYMBOL(MyFunction)
```

In this instance, the actual definition/declaration of MyFunction would exist in a static library, and cannot be changed.

**EDIT:** I discovered that the above macro FORCE_UNDEFINED_SYMBOL does not produce the desired symbol visibility under MSVC. It seems that the only working solution is using pragma comments, ie, __pragma(comment (linker, "/export:" #x)). Maybe a similar solution exists for gcc/ld.

Answer (score 1):

What you're suggesting sounds hard to maintain even if you succeed. You want shared object (DLL) behavior with static libraries.

When I had a similar problem (e.g. 3rd party static lib) I wrapped the lib in a shared object and used that with my application.