# CMake link not subfolder

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

I’m new to cmake.

I want to create code to create instances of some classes (like `ClassA`) and collect them in a handler class. For this i have created a template class `Creator`. 
In each class implementation a instance of this class is created with Creator class. (see `ClassA.cpp` line 8)

I have following folder structure

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
└── SubFolder
    ├── ClassA.cpp
    ├── ClassA.h
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── Creator.h
```

./main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SubFolder/ClassA.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   //classA a;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

./CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(teststaticcmake)

add_executable(teststaticcmake main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(SubFolder)
target_link_libraries(teststaticcmake SubFolder)

install(TARGETS teststaticcmake RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

SubFolder/ClassA.h

```
#ifndef __CLASSA__
#define __CLASSA__

class classA
{
    public:
        classA();
};
#endif //__CLASSA__
```

SubFolder/ClassA.cpp

```
#include "ClassA.h"
#include "Creator.h"

classA::classA()
{
}

classA* pClassA = Creator<classA>::create();
```

SubFolder/Creator.h

```
#ifndef __CREATOR__
#define __CREATOR__

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Creator
{
    public:
        static T* create()
        {
            T* p = new T();

            // Do Something here
            // ... like output
            std::cout << std::endl << "created: " << p;

            return p;
        }
};
#endif //__CREATOR__
```

SubFolder/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(SubFolder ClassA.cpp)
```

I compile this project and run it. So I get only the output "Hello, world!".
When I remove the comment (`main.cpp` line 5) a instance of `ClassA` is used. So I get also the output of class `Creator`. The code for `ClassA` is linked.
When I move the class `ClassA` to root directory it works also.

I have also tried to use parameters like `PUBLIC_LINK`, `debug` and `general` for target_link_libraries. But nothing works.

My intention use a Collection Class in this main.cpp file and get the instanced object from the collection. In the main.ccp file i don't want to know each instanced class because all class `ClassA` ... ClassZ have the same interface (not shown in this example).

How can i force the link of "unused" code?

Edit: Do don't know if it's neccessary. I use KDevelop4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How to force gcc to link an unused static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116420/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-an-unused-static-library)

I've tested your code with GNU 4.8.1 compilers and in your example just replace your `target_link_libraries()` line with:

```
target_link_libraries(
    teststaticcmake 
    PRIVATE
        "-Wl,--whole-archive" 
        SubFolder 
        "-Wl,--no-whole-archive"
)
```

From `target_link_libraries()` [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/target_link_libraries.html):

> - **A link flag**: Item names starting with -, but not -l or -framework, are treated as linker flags. Note that such flags will be treated like any other library link item for purposes of transitive dependencies, so they are generally safe to specify only as private link items that will not propagate to dependents.

**More References**

- [How to force inclusion of an object file in a static library when linking into executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991927/how-to-force-inclusion-of-an-object-file-in-a-static-library-when-linking-into-e)