# CMake is not propagating link dependencies of shared libraries to my executable

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, linker-errors, static-members

I have asked this question in the past but in a different context. I have a C++ application (`App`) which links to a static C++ library A (`libA`), which links to a static C library B (`libB`):

```
# App CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(App ${APP_HEADER_FILES} ${APP_SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(App PUBLIC LibA)

# LibA CMakeLists.txt
add_library(LibA STATIC ${LIBA_HEADER_FILES} ${LIBA_SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(LibA PUBLIC LibB)
```

The problem is that when I build `App` I get a linker error: `"error: undefined reference to mpfit"`. `mpfit` is a function in `libB`. Here is the strange thing now:

- If I make `LibA` shared (by replacing `STATIC` with `SHARED` in CMake) I get no linker error!

Someone told me that I will have to link all the shared libraries to `App` myself. I tried that and it actually worked. But here is my question now:

- Isn't CMake supposed to automatically propagate all the link dependencies to my executable? Isn't this the purpose of the `PUBLIC` keyword in the `target_link_libraries` function?
- Why I get no linker errors when `LibA` is a shared library?

EDIT1:

If that helps: If I do `nm libA` I get:

```
libA.cpp.o:
    // ... blah blah ...
    U mpfit
    // ... blah blah ...
```

Comment: do you have `error: undefined reference to` symbols from `libB`used by `libA`

Comment: @UmNyobe yes, exactly

Comment: If we are talking about e.g. the GNU toolchain you could use [verbose output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994484) to see what's actual called (e.g. on Windows platforms there are [weird workarounds](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Platform/Windows-GNU.cmake#L133) in there). Generally speaking the difference between `STATIC` and `SHARED` here is, that a `SHARED` LibA does actually have LibB linked to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link not subfolder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709241/cmake-link-not-subfolder)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that the linker is dropping non referenced symbols when linking `libB` to `libA`. Which means that by the time you link to `App`, **some** symbols of `libB` are missing.

In that case you may want to specify linkers options to keep the whole `libB` during the first linkage. For instance, for gcc you have [--whole-archive ld parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764041/1122645)